# Delphi - Using Functions in CASE statements

Tags: string, delphi, comparison

In Delphi 10 / Seattle, I am trying to do a nested String test...I have a string, which is a product name. I need to find the product category based on that product name.  This will be case insensitive, and each product will only be in one category.  Once I find a category, I can stop checking...My initial approach would be to do this via AnsiContainsText within a CASE statement, but this is NOT allowed since there is no common function for the CASE statement...

I have an approach that should work, but is there something a little more elegant? I will have about 40 different tests for the category, and will be running (looping through) this test on about 6000 products, so I want something as performant as possible.

```
      // Determine new value...
      Category := '';
      if ((Category = '') and (AnsiContainsText(ProductText, 'PaaS')) then  Category := 'PaaS';
      if ((Category = '') and (AnsiContainsText(ProductText, 'IaaS')) then  Category := 'IaaS';
      if ((Category = '') and (AnsiContainsText(ProductText, 'SaaS')) then  Category := 'SaaS';
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outsource it!

```
function FindCategory(const ProductName: string): string;
const
  categories: TArray<string> = ['PaaS', 'IaaS', 'SaaS']; // can easily be extended
var
  S: string;
begin
  for S in categories do begin
    if ContainsText(ProductName, S) then Exit(S)
  end;
  result := '';
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pos() function :

```
function FindCategory(const ProductName: string): string;
const
  categories: string = 'PaaS,IaaS,SaaS,';
begin
  if Pos(ProductName+ ',', categories)>0 then Exit(ProductName);
  result := '';
end;
```

Comment: The function expects to return a categories item, if a match is found.

Comment: So you can look at to Strutils.AnsiIndexStr() fonction for use a case of.